# Word for "assigning" someone to a group

Tags: translation, english-to-german, single-word-request

What would be the most natural way to translate the following to German:

> I have assigned you to group 1. / I have placed you in group 1.

Basically there are several groups of people and someone has requested to be placed in a specific group.

Is "zuweisen" the correct translation of "assign" in this context, as in *Ich habe Ihnen der Gruppe 1 zugewiesen*? Or is some variant of "zuteilen" more appropriate here?

Comment: You asked for the most natural in translating the phrases. If you meant the most natural way of saying it to someone, it would simply be *"Du bist in Gruppe 1."* or *"Sie sind in Gruppe 1."*

Comment: @Javatasse thanks! I wanted to convey the fact that some action has taken place, not just the result of the action. That's why I didn't like the options you suggest and tried to think of something else.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

"Zuweisen" and "zuteilen" are both correct in this context.

So you can either say

> Ich habe Sie der Gruppe 1 zugewiesen.

or

> Ich habe Sie der Gruppe 1 zugeteilt.

Comment: Ah, so "you" is accusative and "the group" is dative, right? Thanks!

Comment: @GermanMathLearner Yes, that's right.

Comment: Where _»der«_ is optional.

Comment: In a very casual situation you would also hear "Ich habe Sie in Gruppe 1 gesteckt". However, this may be perceived a bit impolite  / objectifying.